# how to add failed_when in ansible tower?

Tags: ansible, yaml

Im trying to add second rescue: in my ansible playbook but it only uses the last rescue
for example: i wanted to run 3 diferent commands if one of them fails
cmd: hostname
fails_when: hostname=TEST
rescue:
cmd: hostname command v2
fails_when: hostname=TEST2
rescue:
cmd: hostname final command
fails_when: hostname=TEST

```
 --- 
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - block:
        - name: hostname start
          command: "hostname"
          register: hostname_start
          failed_when: '"HOSTNAMETEST" in hostname_start.stdout'

       rescue:
        - name: Rescue block V1 (perform recovery)
          command: "ip address"
          register: hostname_start
          failed_when: '"127.0.01" in hostname_start.stdout'

        - name: print hostname
          debug: var=hostname_start

       rescue:   
        - name: Rescue block (perform recovery) V2
          command: "hostname"
          register: hostname_start

        - name: print hostname
          debug: var=hostname_start
```

Comment: You can't have multiple `rescue` blocks. More broadly, you can't have multiple identical keys in the same dictionary; generally, the last one is the one that "wins".

Comment: then what is the best way to make if command 1 fails go to command 2 but if the command 2 works dont go to command 3?

Comment: Register a variable in command 2 and add a `when` statement for command 3 so that it only executes if `command 2` did not execute successfully.

Comment: what if the command 1 fails it will run the rescue command not command 2

Answer (score 1):

I think you may of misunderstood my comment. This is what I am suggesting:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: hostname start
          command: "hostname"
          register: hostname_start
          failed_when: '"HOSTNAMETEST" in hostname_start.stdout'

      rescue:
        - name: Rescue block V1 (perform recovery)
          command: "ip address"
          register: hostname_start_1
          ignore_errors: true
          failed_when: >-
            "127.0.0.1" in hostname_start.stdout

        - name: Rescue block (perform recovery) V2
          when: hostname_start_1 is failed
          command: "hostname"
          register: hostname_start_2

        - set_fact:
            hostname_start: "{{ hostname_start_1 is failed|ternary(hostname_start_2.stdout, hostname_start_1.stdout) }}"

    - name: print hostname
      debug: var=hostname_start
```

If the first `command` task fails, Ansible will enter the `rescue` block. The second command will only run if the first command fails. The `set_fact` command picks the value from the successful command.

Comment: Yeah, good catch. I wrote that in a hurry. Let me fix it up...